# Ruby on Rails passing view variable to model and back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

Hi I have difficult times to understand why I get # instead of correct value

[image]
View:

```
<%= form_tag root_url, method: :get do %>
<p>
 <%= text_field_tag :zip_code, params[:zip_code] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Lookup", name: nil %>
 </p>
<% end %>

  <% if @zip_code %>
  <dl id ="zip_info">
    <dd> <%=  @zip_code %> </dd>
  </dl>
 <% end %>
```

Model:

```
class ZipCode < ActiveRecord::Base
    def initialize(zip) 
      return zip
    end       
end
```

Controller:

```
class ZipCodeLookupController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @zip_code = ZipCode.new(params[:zip_code]) #(params[:zip_code]) if params[:zip_code].present?
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are showing `@zip_code` which is an object of `ZipCode` class.

`#ZipCode:0x8d4b030` refers to the `ZipCode` object at memory address `0x8d4b030`.

In order to the see the attribute/column values of `@zip_code` object, you need to do this:

```
<dd> <%=  @zip_code.attribute_1 %> </dd>
<dd> <%=  @zip_code.attribute_2 %> </dd>
```

etc.

Comment: yes, It is an object but I never instantiated. The way I interpreted for my self is user sent value via params[:zip_code] to controller and controller  call model and model just returns its parameters! why it should be an object here?

Comment: You are right, you never instantiated. If you do: `puts @zip_code.inspect` in your controller, you will see, it gives you: `#<ZipCode not initialized>`.

Comment: Thanks, I am very beginner

Comment: Welcome, no problem :)